# Is it also possible to insert the comment feature in the wall feed?

Tags: facebook

On Facebook. A live wall feed plugin. Within that plugin; is it possible to insert a own comment feature?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible. However, you will need to save the comments on your own database while retrieving the wall posts from Facebook. This may be a little tough considering the fact that you'll need to map the comments on the database to the wall posts from Facebook.

I'm not sure how the plugin works - If it retrieves the Facebook data without storing it, then it may be a problem.

One possible work around maybe:

1. Store the Facebook wall post in your database (Table1) and store the corresponding comments in Table2.
2. While displaying to users, pull the facebook and local comments from the database.

One caveat is that the Facebook data will not be current.